# error variance calculations for reliability analysis of a composite metric in HLM

Tags: variance, reliability, composite

I am trying to determine how to obtain within-group variance for a composite measure based on a set of (weighted) proportions.

I have 50 groups being compared on 8 proportion measures, with 4 measures weighted as 1/5 and 4 measures weighted at 1/20. There is a composite score for each group that is the 8 rates multiplied by the weights and summed. Now I need the variance of each group's composite score in order to use in a HLM.

The RAND tech report "The Reliability of Provider Profiling" has a nice overview (and SAS code) for individual binomial measures, but the tutorial turns suddenly obscure for assessing the reliability of the composite, particularly with weighted proportions. On p. 31: "For the weighted combination of several binary measures, the sampling variance can be calculated by multiplying the variances of individual measures by the squared weights and summing the components."

MAIN QUESTION: So, does that mean a) the individual measure's variance is (p(1-p))/n) since it is a proportion, and b) I'd multiply that by the weight squared, so c) the weighted variances for each measure are summed to make the final errorvariance value for each group's composite score? It seems like that's what the tutorial implies. Or do you need to divide the summed, weighted variance by N to obtain the final variance value? (I've seen that formula in passing.) Or are neither appropriate?

Related questions how are variances obtained for these two situations: 1) what if your composite is an O/E where E is the overall mean? 2) what if your data are continuous?